# I Image Device All Day - And want to run multiple BIOS/UEFI environments for Training/Testing - What do wise ones?

Tags: bios, virtualization, uefi, imaging

I'm an L2 Support Tech, and as part of my daily activities, I provide assistance walking stores through reimaging their POS/Hardware systems. We mainly support six or so set units. These devices are standard in the industry, but each has its own BIOS/UEFI configuration process.

The guides we use are outdated and often do not contain solutions for issues encountered during the process.

Would there be a way for me to set up multiple environments where I could practice and test several separate BIOS/UEFI configurations? From key combos pressed to trigger bios/boot menu, to the options within each configuration.

Would it be possible to run a VM with only BIOS? Could I install a generic OS in a VM and emulate the hardware/install the bios there?

I'm not sure how to best do this, or if it's even possible. Would anyone have some ideas?

Comment: I think this question is better suited to Software Recommendations site

Comment: @RohitGupta Maybe, but it will jut get closed there as well.

Comment: I believe it was IBM that had a website with animated and fully interactive BIOS mockups for all their systems. This was 12 or so years ago, and I doubt they've maintained this.

Comment: Ask your org to buy an extra of each device for this testing. That's probably the best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.

Virtual machines don't use BIOS like you find on a physical machine. That wouldn't work, as they are designed to work on actual hardware.

Virtual machine software uses its own custom BIOS that the hypervisor (VM software) uses to intercept calls. They aren't replaceable, or very customizable, as they are designed solely to work with their software.

Comment: I'm open to other possible solutions, but none come to mind. I assume the same would be true for Docker/Containers. Granted, I know very little about these.

How would situations requiring BIOS change management work in a larger corporation? Is this only tested on real hardware?

Comment: @CowFieldTechGuy Large corporations tend to buy the same model computer in bulk.  Also, they typically dont need to change anything in BIOS, anyway.  Depending on the vendor and really the amount of money they spent, they can request BIOS settings be done before the machines are shipped.   Granted, if a setting needs to be changed locally, its tested on a test machine, possibly then tested with a few users, then some tech goes around to each machine and updates it.